# Searching Text File and file list view based on criteria

Tags: vb.net

Everyone,

I have been working on a program to manage our home finances.  This is a program I am writing to further my knowledge of VB.NET.  So far everything is going great but I am stuck at one point.  I have a tabbed view setup in my main form.  The tabs are `Bills`, `Income` and `Summary`.  I am on the last tab (`summary`).  Right now I have the bills written to a text file and the following items are separated by a `|`.  The items placed in the file are:

```
Paid To | Date | Amount | Paid By | Confirmation Number | Notes
```

I have a ListView setup on my summary tab.  The first column is to list the bills that we pay.  The rest of the columns are months with a final total at the end (not worried about those yet).  What I am having trouble with is searching through the text file for current year only records and listing out the `Pay To` in the first column of the ListView.

Here is the code that runs in the function.  I calls a second function to fill the ListView column.

```
    Try
        sr = New StreamReader(MainBillsFile, True)
        Dim ListBills As New List(Of String)
        While (sr.Peek() > -1)
           BillitmsSum = sr.ReadLine().Split("|")
           Dim dateValue As Date = Date.Parse(BillitmsSum(1))
           Dim DateYear As String = dateValue.Year

           If DateYear = CurrentYear Then
            BillitmPayTo = BillitmsSum(0)
           End If
           Output_On_Launch_BillSum()
       End While
       sr.Close()
       sr.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Reading From File." & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

When this runs when the program is loaded is the following.

Lets say I have 4 items in the file 2 with 2015 dates and 2 with 2014 dates.  Based on what I want to show (current year 2015) I get the following

```
2015 item 1
2015 item 2
2015 item 2
2015 item 2
```

What I think is happening is the code is seeing all the items (4 total) and pulling the 2015 ones as it should but to fill up everything is is duplicating the last item to match the total items in the file of 4.

I hope this all makes sense.  This is my first post here, up to this point searching has helped me greatly but I have tried a bunch of different code and they all give the same out come.

Here is the other Method:

```
Sub Output_On_Launch_BillSum()
    Dim LVItem3 As ListViewItem = LVBillSum.Items.Add(BillitmPayTo)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us the Output_On_Launch_BillSum() Method.

Comment: added the other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it appears you need to call Output_On_Launch_BillSum() only if the year of the bill is the current date.  I'd need to see that method to be sure though.

```
       If DateYear = CurrentYear Then
        BillitmPayTo = BillitmsSum(0)
        Output_On_Launch_BillSum()    
       End If
```

Comment: I added the other method to OP

Comment: That did it.  I had a feeling I was missing something small.  Like I said this has been hounding me for a few days.  I think I was just looking at it for to long.  Thank you for your help.  I know only have 2 records showing out of 4 which is correct.